# Unable to refer to a textbox because I haven't created it yet

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB to make a file editing system that allows the user to edit multiple files on multiple tabs like Notpad++.

I hit a slight snag though. Seeing as tabs don't contain text, I add a textbox to each tab upon creation.

For loading files I want to check if the current tab's textbox is empty so I don't end up adding the loaded file as a new tab, which would just create clutter (like how when word opens a file, it checks if the current document is an unsaved file with no text before loading.)

Problem is, how do I check this with tabs I haven't added yet? (Ie will be added whilst the program is running as opposed to in design mode)

If anyone knows the answer, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: VB.Net can do almost exactly the same things C# can.  You're VERY unlikely to see trolling on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've seen it once before when someone asked about using 3D in visual basic. Might not have been here but I remember someone giving a sarcastic 'you're joking right' supply. I have a bit of paranoia about VB being laughed at since it's all I can do at the moment and from what I've done with it, it deserves more credit than a lot of people give it.

Comment: `but I remember someone giving a sarcastic 'you're joking right' supply.` I agree with @EricJ. I doubt that you'd get that kind of reaction here :) I've seen a more matured crowd in SO. But then every site has those few who `are` different ;). Besides few differences, C# & VB are just the same and VB.Net can do almost exactly the same things C# can. In fact, they both share the same development team in MS. MS has never shown VB inferior to C# or vice versa. If you are a VB fan (like me) then continue coding in VB and if you like C# then simply continue coding in that. :) Editing your post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know VB.NET, but I have made this code in C# which checks to see if a `TabPage` contains a `TextBox` which is empty. I think it's easy to translate it to VB.NET if you know that language.

Here is the function that checks to see if a TabPage contains an empty TextBox. The function receives the TabPage as its parameter and returns `true` or `false`.

```
private bool ContainsEmptyTextBox(TabPage tp)
{
    bool foundTextBox = false;
    bool textBoxIsEmpty = false;
    foreach (Control c in tp.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            foundTextBox = true;
            TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
            {
                textBoxIsEmpty = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (foundTextBox == true && textBoxIsEmpty == true)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

And here is how you can use that function to iterate trough all the tabs in a `TabControl` and see which one contains an empty TextBox:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        if (ContainsEmptyTextBox(tp))
        {
            // This tabpage contains an empty textbox
            MessageBox.Show(tabControl1.TabPages.IndexOf(tp) + " contains an empty textbox");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I used [this site](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to automatically convert the C# code into VB.NET.

```
Private Function ContainsEmptyTextBox(tp As TabPage) As Boolean
    Dim foundTextBox As Boolean = False
    Dim textBoxIsEmpty As Boolean = False
    For Each c As Control In tp.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
            foundTextBox = True
            Dim tb As TextBox = TryCast(c, TextBox)
            If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text) Then
                textBoxIsEmpty = True
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If foundTextBox = True AndAlso textBoxIsEmpty = True Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function


Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each tp As TabPage In tabControl1.TabPages
        If ContainsEmptyTextBox(tp) Then
            ' This tabpage contains an empty textbox
            MessageBox.Show(tabControl1.TabPages.IndexOf(tp) & " contains an empty textbox")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you gave me is a bit complicated for Vb, but it did give me an idea. The contains thing reminded me about collections, which reminded me of the "for each" syntax. In short, it reminded me of something that helped me get it working so now it loads perfectly into blank files. You didn't give me the exact code, but your reply made me think of a way to do things, which in a way is better since it means I know the code inside out instead of using someone else's code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I also had to make a Notepad++ clone in C#, that needed to support editing multiple files in tabs. I remember that I had a `List<string> OpenFiles` member in my form that contained the filenames of the open files. Each time I opened a new file, I would do this:

- Add a new item to `OpenFiles`
- Create a new tab with a textbox and add it to the TabControl

In this way, the `OpenFiles` list was synchronized with the tabs in the TabControl. For example, item 3 in `OpenFiles` was the filename for the 4th tab in the TabControl.

Of course, when I opened a new file, I needed to check if the file was opened before. If it was opened before, I switched to its tab; if not, I would open a new tab.

Having the `OpenFiles` member, this was easy. The full algorithm for opening files was this:

- Check to see if the file is already open by searching the `OpenFiles` list
- If the file is already open (if it exists in `OpenFiles`), and its position in `OpenFiles` is `idx`(for example), then activate the `idx`th tab
- If the file does not exist in `OpenFiles`

  - Add it to `OpenFiles` at the end
  - Add a new tab with a textbox to the end of the TabControl

When closing a file (for example closing the `idx`th tab), I did this:

- Check if the file has been saved, if not prompt the user if he wants to save it or not (Yes/No/Cancel messagebox).

  - If he chose yes, then save it and continue
  - If he chose no, then don't save it and continue
  - If he chose cancel, then abort the operation (return)
- Remove the `idx`th tab from the TabControl
- Remove the `idx`th item in the `OpenFiles` list

I think you can apply the same logic in your application.

Comment: I have a similar system in place already for tracking filepaths. I used a listbox for storing the filepaths of loaded files, and for new unsaved files it reads 'unsaved'. What I was trying to do was have a variable set as textbox and then when the corresponding tab got focus, change that variable to the textbox, which obviously wasn't working. I had a variable for the textbox so I could know which active textbox to check for text and pass the loaded text into. Could you perhaps give me some example code as I have not used the list<string>openfiles before and I always find examples useful.

Comment: If you say you have a similar system in place, I don't think I understand what your problem is. Do you want to check to see if a tab has a textbox that is empty? What do you want to do if you find a tab that has an empty textbox?

Comment: The system I have tracks a string by adding it to an invisible listbox, but I need to track the text content of textboxes, some of which are created during the program running as opposed to at design.If the program finds an empty textbox in an unsaved file, I want it to load a file into that textbox using a streamwriter.

Comment: What if that empty textbox belongs to a file that the user created but hasn't modified yet. Let's say in Notepad++, I click File->New, and I get a new tab. Then I click File->Open, select a file, then the tab I opened before will get replaced. As a user, I would not want that. Is that what you want?

Comment: The text will only be replaced if the file is both unsaved and has no text. If the file is unsaved, it won't have a filepath assigned to it, it will read "Unsaved" (similar to word's "untitled"). After ruling out a filepath, it's simply a matter of testing the textbox for text, which is what I'm struggling with. I could make the file open in a new tab everytime, but that's just going to make things cluttered. I know it seems petty, but my file editor is designed for people who are lazy and lazy people can't be bothered to close a tab, on top of which I am aiming to combine useful elements.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. I will reply with another answer shortly.